# FullCalendar plugin not rendering events on calendar

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, fullcalendar

I am using `fullCalendar` plugin to display events from ASP.NET ASMX web service. JSON data is fetched correct and displayed ok in the console. But events are not rendered on the calendar view. What am I missing?

```
$('#divcalendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: '2018-03-12',
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  events: function (start, end, timezone,callback) {

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'Webservice.asmx/ListEvents',
          cache: false,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) {
              var event = [];
              $(data.d).each(function () {
                  event.push({
                      title: this.Title,
                      start: this.Start,
                      end: this.End
                  });
              });
              console.log(event);
              callback(event);
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert('There was an error');
          }
      });
  }

});


[WebMethod]
public CalendarEvent[] ListEvents()
{
    DateTime epoc = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    return new CalendarEvent[]
    {
    new CalendarEvent { Title = "Event 1", Start = new DateTime(2018,3,9,16,0,0).Subtract(epoc).TotalSeconds, End = new DateTime(2018,3,9,17,0,0).Subtract(epoc).TotalSeconds},
    new CalendarEvent { Title = "Event 2", Start = new DateTime(2018,3,12,12,0,0).Subtract(epoc).TotalSeconds, End = new DateTime(2018,3,12,13,0,0).Subtract(epoc).TotalSeconds}
    };
}
```

Console output from webservice

```
{"d":[{"__type":"CalendarEvent","End":1520614800,"Start":1520611200,"Title":"Event 1"},{"__type":"CalendarEvent","End":1520859600,"Start":1520856000,"Title":"Event 2"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your dates *are* being entered into the calendar, but not in the place you intended.

Although you haven't mentioned it explicitly, I would strongly suspect that the timestamps you're outputting for your start and end dates are specified in seconds.

Now, fullCalendar uses momentJS to parse any date strings or timestamps supplied to it. Alternatively it can accept ready-made momentJS or JS Date objects.

momentJS can parse timestamps automatically through the momentJS constructor (which fullCalendar is calling when it receives your timestamp value), but it assumes the value is given in *milliseconds*, not seconds.

Therefore when you supply it with, for instance, `1520611200` (the start date of your first event), it interprets that in milliseconds and the resulting date is `1970-01-18 14:23:31`.

If you want to specify the date in seconds you have to use the moment.unix() method instead. Using this method, your timestamp is instead interpreted as `2018-03-09 16:00:00`, which I assume is what you intended.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Loccoxds/1/ for a demo to see the difference in how momentJS parses one of your values.

To get your code working, the simplest way is to do this:

```
success: function (data) {
      var event = [];
      $(data.d).each(function () {
          event.push({
              title: this.Title,
              start: moment.unix(this.Start),
              end: moment.unix(this.End)
          });
      });
      console.log(event);
      callback(event);
  },
```

This way, you supply a ready-made momentJS object to fullCalendar, having correctly parsed the timestamp.

See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/ for more details about parsing timestamps in momentJS

---

P.S. Alternatively of course you could change your asmx service to output the dates in a format momentJS can parse automatically, such as a timestamp in milliseconds, or an ISO8601-formatted date string - see http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/ for details of that.

P.P.S. ASMX is pretty much a legacy technology within .NET now. You should consider using WCF or Web API instead. Microsoft recommends not to create new code using ASMX.

Comment: Its now working, Thank you so much. Is it possible that I convert milliseconds to seconds on the server side so that I do not need `moment.unix` in javascript?

Comment: You could just divide the number of seconds by 1000. Or you can google other methods of doing it. Or you could just output your Date in ISO8601 format as I mentioned. Running `ToString("o")` on the DateTime should do it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings